# Music plays when I stop a Call

Tags: iphone

This has been happening for a week or so, since the last IOS Update.
When I make a call and I stop the call, music plays from my music app, but the app is turned off.
How can I make this stop?
Thanks

Comment: I have noticed the same behavior when connected to Bluetooth, when a call is ended the last played audio, Audible in my case, starts playing.